# Как в строку с input вставить еще одну переменную?

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

Нужно запросить число у пользователя - 7

Людей в 30-м секторе: 7

но при этом, 30 - это тоже переменная. Как ее правильно добавить?

int(input('Людей в ....-м секторе: '))

Comment: запрашивайте свои переменный поочередно. Сначала номер сектора, потом - количество людей.

Comment: Ну либо можно через пробел вводить данные и потом разносить их на две переменные.

Comment: sektor=30 ... 
ludi=int(input('Людей в '+str(sektor)+'-м секторе: '))

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы! Извините, что так коряво описал ситуацию. Я просто совсем новичок. Интик, я именно это и имел ввиду. Такая строка - visitors = int(input('Людей в '+str(area)+'-м секторе: '))  Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проблема в том чтобы вставить значение то можно воспользоваться fstring:

```
sector_number = int(input())
people_in_sector = int(input(f'Людей в {sector_number}-м секторе:'))
```

можно и так:

```
people_in_sector = int(input(f'Людей в {int(input())}-м секторе:'))
```